# Auto start a GUI application when a VNC (Xtightvnc) start

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vnc

Please help me to do auto start a GUI application when a VNC (Xtightvnc) start. This application should start inside VNC session and I have to see running application when I connect to the server via VNC client. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I have tried below steps but didn't work.

`vim .vnc/xstartup`

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
xterm -e  "cd /home/user/appfolder &&  ./launchapp"
```

VNC is working without any issues, but the app is not starting.

Error log `.xsession-errors` is empty. Unable to find any errors related to this.

I have configured the same in XFCE startup. That also didn't work.

Comment: How exactly does this fail? Does XFCE start when you run VNC?

Comment: VNC is working without any issues, but app is not starting.

Comment: What's in your `.xsession-errors` or similar? Probably [edit] your question rather than bury relevant information down here in comments.

Comment: @tripleee  modified the question as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure it's running `.vnc/xstartup` and not something else?

Comment: .vnc/xstartup is executing when VNC start. I have tested that. But only this GUI based one is not loading.